# Chrome HTML5 Built in video controls css

Tags: google-chrome, css, html5-video

Is there a way to have access to the css of Chrome's built in HTML5 video controls rather then just on a global level?

For instance, if you were to include the styles

```
input[type=button], input[type=range] {
  display: none;
}
```

There will no longer be any controls for the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want Chrome's native css? this is Chrome's: http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/mediaControlsChromium.css
this is Safari's: http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/mediaControls.css